# Using #include when initializing a constexpr (string ?)

Tags: c++, macros

I came across this piece of code and I don't know how it works--I've never seen include used this way:

```
static constexpr auto VAR_NAME = 
    #include "path/to/file/FileName"
;
```

and the file path/to/file/FileName contains the contents of some string, i.e.

```
R"(
contents of string
)"
```

Could someone please explain what this code does?

Comment: `#include` simply dumps the contents of the included file into the current file, as if you physically copy/pasted those contents in place of the `#include` directive. There's no black magic.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Please put your answers in the answer section where they can be peer reviewed and accepted. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's exactly what it says: [the contents of the named file are "included" into your source code](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.include#2).

This can be done on any line of your source. It just literally pastes the file contents in. So, the resulting code is:

```
static constexpr auto VAR_NAME = 
R"(
contents of string
)"
;
```

Presumably it was of use to the original author to keep the string literal in a separate file, possibly to make localisation easier, or maybe just for "neatness".

`#include` doesn't *have* to be for header files (though that is the normal application).

Answer (score 0):

It does what include does, just includes the content of the file where the include directive was 'called'.

#include  replaces that line with the contents of the file.

There are two variants of the include, using <> or using "" (ie: #include "file"),
the first one searches for the file in system wide common locations , the second one searches for the file in local specified locations (ie: specified in the compiler flags)